# How to convert Mysql query to relational algebra?

Tags: mysql, relational-algebra

How to write mysql query
`SELECT book, COUNT(book) FROM booking GROUP BY book;` in relational algebra? 
I thought `Gcount(book)(booking)` but doesn't seem right.

I am following standards of Database Management Systems by Arun K Majumdar and Pritimoy Bhattacharya. Thanks in advance.

Comment: u try -- we try

Comment: If that's not available online, then tell us what the operators are and how they work exactly and what a relation looks like (are columns ordered, are column names unique, etc.). Or give an online reference to descriptions of operators that are the same. There is no one single relational algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Modified your SQL command to this :

`select booking.book,count(booking.book) as book_count
from booking
GROUP BY booking.book`

Equivalent Relational Algebra command :

`π booking.book, book_count γ booking.book; 
COUNT(booking.book)→book_count booking`

Source : http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc.htm

I hope this Helped!

Comment: But that "relational algebra" is not a standard one, and has some facilities like sql that form a relational *language* but does not just involve a bunch of operators on values, as an "algebra" is intended to be. Ie it's *not* an algebra. In particular, its grouping and sorting are not algebraic & beg the question of what their expression in algebraic terms would be.